# Mocking a class inside the tested method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have a problem with a class I have to mock.

The tested method looks like this:

```
testedMethod(Date from, Date to, Set set1, Set set2, SomeContext context) { method body };
```

Now inside the method body, there is a class used. The usage looks like this:

```
List list = ComponentsFetcher.getComponent(String string1, context, from, to, String string2);
```

The whole tested method (a bit simplified) looks like this:

```
public static final long testedMethod(Date from, Date to, Set set1, Set set2, SomeContext context) {

    long returnedLong = 0;

    List list1 = ComponentsFetcher.getComponent(String string1, context, from, to, String string2);
    List list2 = ComponentsFetcher.getComponent(String string3, context, from, to, String string4);

    returnedLong = TestedMethodsClass.anotherMethod(from, to, set1, set2, list1, list2

    return returnedLong;

};
```

This `ComponentsFetcher.getComponent()` method is doing many things, but ALL I need here is to get this `list`, I know how is this list looking like, I can simply create it and use it later in the tested method.

So I am wanting to mock the  `ComponentsFetcher.getComponent()` like this:

```
private void mockComponentsFetcher(Date from, Date to, ComponentsContext context, List list1, List list2) throws SomeBusinessException {
    Mockito.mock(ComponentsFetcher.class);
    Mockito.when(ComponentsFetcher.getComponent(string1, context, from, to, string2)).thenReturn(list1);
    Mockito.when(ComponentsFetcher.getComponent(string3, context, from, to, string4)).thenReturn(list2);
    }
```

Finally, the `@Test` method:

```
@Test
    public void testTestedMethod() throws ParseException, SomeBusinessException {
        //given
        Date from = DateHelper.getDate(2011, 07, 03);
        Date to = DateHelper.getDate(2012, 07, 03);
        Set set1 = null; // can be null
        Set set2 = DateHelper.getDate(2011, 07, 03);
                Date day = DateHelper.getDate(2011, 07, 03);

        List list1 = getList(new Date[]{
                                // contents of the list
               });
        List list2 = getList(new Date[]{
                                // contents of the list
               });

        //mock
        ComponentsContext context = mockContext(day);
```

// This context REALLY DOESNT matter, it is mocked just for the method to run.

// here is the main problem, I have no idea how to use this mocked ComponentsFetcher, while it is used INSIDE the testedMethod

```
        mockComponentsFetcher(from, to, context, list1, list2);
        //when
        long months = TestedMethodsClass.testedMethod(from, to, set1, set2, context);
        //then
        long awaited = 12;
        assertThat(months).isEqualTo(awaited);
    }
```

But it ain't working at all...

Comment: First of all, what is `ComponentsFetcher` exactly? It is unclear from your code. By the Java naming conventions, this seems to be a utility class and `.getComponent()` a static method on it. You cannot mock such methods easily, short of using some PowerMock* framework.

Comment: @fge - As I said in the question - the `ComponentsFetcher` is a tough guy, but all this class and its method `getComponent` is doing in the tested method is returning a `List` and I am perfectly able to make this list on my own which is what I'm doing ;)

Comment: That doesn't answer my initial question; is that a utility class with only static methods? The Mockito code you showed to mock it won't work as far as I can see.

Comment: @fge - it is a utility class with only static methods.

Comment: Then your mocking code can't work. You can't mock static methods that easily. A redesign is in order, or you have to use PowerMockito; and the former solution is preferred...

Answer (score 2):

You can't mock static methods using mockito. If you want to stay with mockito, try to redesign your class so that the method is not static and then mock the actual instance of the object.

For unit testing's sake, it is always preferred to avoid global singletons (due to exactly the problem you had) and rely instead on [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). What this means is that you would create your ComponentsFetcher somewhere else in the code and pass it to your class under test, probably at construction time. This will allow you to inject a mocked one when preparing your unit test and use a real one when in production